# Draggable overflow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

Please help, I want to have that green box can be dragged in its parent, but it also can overflow from its parent, and will be hidden when it's (green box) moved or dragged over the line. Can someone help me?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#child").draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Please help, here's the fiddle for example : http://jsfiddle.net/vbJHJ/9/

I read http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/ but nothing can help me.. :(

Answer (score 2):

You're over complicating things. KISS it. Take off containment and add css overflow to parent.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#child").draggable();
});​
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width:300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #00ff00;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

​

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vbJHJ/9/)

Answer (score 0):

**BEST SOLUTION EVER:**
you said you want to make hidden box if moved over the line use this and vote up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#child").draggable({
drag : function() {
var bT = $("#parent").offset().top;
var bL = $("#parent").offset().left;
var bLL = bL+$("#parent").width()-$(this).width();
var bTT = bT+$("#parent").height()-$(this).height();
var m = $(this).offset();
if( m.top < bT || m.left < bL || m.left > bLL || m.top > bTT) {
$(this).css({ "opacity" : "0.1" });  
}
else {
$(this).css({ "opacity" : "1" });
}
}
});
});​
```